# How do I identify which remote branches a given SHA-1 "belongs to"?

Tags: git

We store the SHA-1 of the current checkout when building our Maven artifacts, so we can go back to the exact commit from which the artifact was made with "git checkout SHA-1".  This results in a detached HEAD not belonging to any branches.

I can then use "gitk --all ." to visually identify the remote branch(es) that the commit belongs to, but I would like to know the corresponding git command for establishing which branch the current commit "belongs to" (EDIT: as there may have been other bugs fixed on the branch since this particular build).

Comment: Why do you want to know which *remote* branch it belongs to? Ain't local branch sufficient?

Comment: All development happen on a branch. This is to be certain that the right branch is chosen for bug fixing.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ git branch -r --contains <SHA-1>
```

This will potentially give you more than one branch, and won't tell you which is the most 'recent'.

Comment: This creates a branch named `-r` starting at `<SHA-1>`

Comment: @CharlesB: no, this works fine - it shows all remote-tracking branches that contain `<SHA1>`....

Comment: @MarkLongair: Doesn't work for me, must be a bug on my config (Git 1.7.8 on Mac OS X Lion), I keep getting that `-r` branch. Will remove my downvote when post is edited (currently vote is locked)

Comment: @CharlesB: that's very strange - I've just tried git 1.7.8 on Linux here, and it's fine...

Answer (score 1):

from `git help branch`

> With --contains, shows only the branches that contain the named commit
>   (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are
>          descendants of the named commit). With --merged, only branches merged into the named commit (i.e. the branches whose tip commits
>          are reachable from the named commit) will be listed. With --no-merged only branches not merged into the named commit will be
>          listed. If the  argument is missing it defaults to HEAD (i.e. the tip of the current branch).

So I guess you are looking for `git branch --contains SHA-1`

To list remote branches, first you need to fetch all the remote branches, and then give `-r` option to the above command.

```
git fetch
git branch -r --contains SHA-1
```

Comment: This doesn't list remote branches